# Outputting a PDO request from mySQL into a dropdown selector list

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I have a table with 2 columns and i am looking to output only one of these columns into a drop down selector list with a button at the bottom. I am using PDO to connect to the database, This code is working but it is only giving me an array of all of the details of each row.

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$username = "mydb";
$password = "mydb"; 
$member = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=mydb', $username, $password);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT list_name FROM lists WHERE member_id = :member_id ');
    $sth->execute(array('member_id' => $member));
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

  if ( count($result) ) { 
    foreach($result as $row) {
      print_r($row);
    }   
  } else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

This is the working code so far, how to i change the output from an array to a selector drop down list with buttons? even a scrolling box list would do?

Comment: there is absolutely no need to use `fetchAll()` if the next thing you intend to do is iterate over the results. Remove the `$result = $sth->fetchAll();` and change `count($result)` into `$result->rowCount() > 0` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just trying to display a query result in a drop down box.
This is only html depending on some variables.
Instead of displaying results like this :

```
foreach($result as $row) {
   print_r($row);
}
```

you should display an HTML  tag with PHP like this :

```
print '<select id="your_list">';
    foreach ($result as $row) {
    print '<option value="'.$row['list_name'].'">'.$row['list_name'].'</option>';
    }
print '</select>';
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
```

If you want be able to submit this form and get the value, you have to surround it with a form tag with right options.

Answer (score 0):

You access the element in the array by column name e.g. `$row['list_name']`

Something like:

```
<select name='x'>

<?php   
    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['list_name']."'>".$row['list_name']."</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
```